# Ubuntu 22.04 suddenly no display, keyboard, mouse, or GRUB

Tags: boot, display, suspend, asus

My Asus Vivobook that runs Ubuntu 22.04 suddenly stopped working with no trigger event. I'm unable to resume from sleep mode after allowing the computer to be idle with the lid/screen up. After many hard reboots I got my display and keyboard/mouse back, but after allowing "sleep" again the problem is back and I cannot resolve it.

On board display is totally black, keyboard and mouse pad input isn't recognized on boot. If I connect an external display and peripherals it boots and works fine, but I'm unable to boot into GRUB to boot in graphic safe mode, or even to reinstall the OS. After taking longer than normal I go straight to login screen without first seeing Ubuntu splash screen.

No modifications, stock laptop with AMD graphics on motherboard. I ran all updates, but no change. What else can I try?

Comment: Boot from a Live Media USB and choose try.